# Correlation function over multiple data frames in R

Tags: r, function

I'm kind of stucked in my data analysis.
I have multiple data frames with which I need to do correlation analysis. And I want to pack the parameters of cor.test into a list of data frames. Each data frame is a product of splitted data frame by a factor variable and only contain 2 variables (those of interest).  I need to do this for several variables throughout my research project so it would be good to have a function for it in future.

The Rcode:

```
get_correlation_parameters <- function(objectname,factorvar){
  datalist <- mget(ls(pattern = print(objectname))) 
 parameters <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(factorvar)) {
    x <- datalist[[i]][,1]
    y <- datalist[[i]][,2]
    test <- cor.test(x,y)
    DF <- data.frame(test$estimate, test$conf.int, test$p.value)
    parameters <- c(parameters, DF[i]) }
}
```

Can someone help me to find the mistake?
I tried so many things and I cannot overcome my own biased mind.
It would be also good if I could easily specifiy the method used for the correlation statistics (e.g pearson, spearman,...). I guess one could adjust this in the function input argument
Many thanks,

Cherrio,
Nadine

Comment: try reading the "many models" chapter here and see if that gives you some inspiration? https://r4ds.had.co.nz/

Comment: Hi, thanks I definitely will check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information on your data, it is hard to be specific, but here is an example using a data set `iris` that is included with R. It has various measurements for each of three species of iris. The basic steps are to split the data frame into a list containing three data frames, one for each species. Then use `lapply` three times, once to run the correlation test, a second time to extract the statistics you want, and a third time because the confidence intervals are a vector not a scalar value. Hopefully this will be similar to the organization of your data:

```
data(iris)
iris.lst <- split(iris[, 1:2], iris$Species)
results.lst <- lapply(iris.lst, function(x) cor.test(x[, 1], x[, 2], method="pearson"))
results.stats <- lapply(results.lst, "[", c("estimate", "conf.int", "p.value"))
stats <- do.call(rbind, lapply(results.stats, unlist))
stats
#            estimate.cor conf.int1 conf.int2      p.value
# setosa        0.7425467 0.5851391 0.8460314 6.709843e-10
# versicolor    0.5259107 0.2900175 0.7015599 8.771860e-05
# virginica     0.4572278 0.2049657 0.6525292 8.434625e-04
```

The `stats` object is a matrix, to turn it into a data frame use:

```
stats <- data.frame(stats)
```

Comment: Thanks this looks like my solution. Sorry I did not know how to share my data. I will attach simulated data in future for this case. Will let you know if it worked. Many thanks :)

Comment: Okay, this is exactly what I was looking for. 
I don't know why I was thinking in such confused ways.
Thank you so much, I am very happy now!